# Random sphere packing density

Tags: geometry, spheres

Inside a cube, we repetedly pick random points where a sphere with a diameter of 1 can be placed, until no more spheres can be placed. We then measure the percentage of space used up by the spheres.

What is this percentage (assuming that the cube is infinitely larger than the spheres, so that its sides don't matter)?

Comment: Related?: [Packing density of randomly deposited circles on a plane](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63087/packing-density-of-randomly-deposited-circles-on-a-plane).